# Exporting namespaces in ambient declarations while referencing other namespaces

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to create an ambient type declaration for Turf.js. It can be imported from npm either with all functions, or piecemeal, one module at a time.

I have a main namespace which contains all the function declarations:

```
declare namespace turf {
    export function area(input: GeoJSON.Feature<any> | GeoJSON.FeatureCollection<any>): number;
    export function bearing(start: GeoJSON.Feature<GeoJSON.Point>, end: GeoJSON.Feature<GeoJSON.Point>): number;
    ...
    export function feature(geometry: GeoJSON.GeometryObject, properties?: any): GeoJSON.FeatureCollection<any>;
    export function point(coordinates: GeoJSON.Position, properties?: any): GeoJSON.Feature<GeoJSON.Point>;

}
```

For the monolithic export, I can do this:

```
declare module "turf" {
    export = turf;
}
```

And for normal piecemeal module exports I can do this:

```
declare module "@turf/area" {
    export default turf.area;
}

declare module "@turf/bearing" {
    export default turf.bearing;
}
```

Which can then be used like this:

```
import bearing from "@turf/bearing";
```

The turf library also has a module called `@turf/helpers`, which is used like this:

`import { feature, point } from "@turf/helpers"`

My question is, how do I type the export of the "@turf/helpers" module? I do not want to copy the type definition, but use the ones already in the turf namespace.

The closest I've been able to achieve is this:

```
declare module "@turf/helpers" {
    export = {
        feature: turf.feature,
        point: turf.point,
    }
}
```

But since I'm not exporting a module, I have to use the `import x = require(...)` format in my implementation:

```
import helpers = require("@turf/helpers");
const { feature, point } = helpers;
feature(...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved using the `export import ... = ...` construct.

(Sidenote: I also learnt that not all functions in the `@turf/helpers` package were available in `@turf`, which will be illustrated with `distanceToDegrees`.)

I created a nested namespace within the turf namespace, and then explicitly declared which declarations should be exported from the helpers namespace:

```
declare namespace turf {
    ...
    namespace helpers {
        // Should be imported as turf.feature and turf.point
        export function feature(geometry: GeoJSON.GeometryObject, properties?: any): GeoJSON.FeatureCollection<any>;
        export function point(coordinates: GeoJSON.Position, properties?: any): GeoJSON.Feature<GeoJSON.Point>;
        ...
        // Should not be included in turf, only able to be imported from @turf/helpers
        export function distanceToDegrees(distance: number, unit?: Unit): number;
    }

    export import feature = helpers.feature;
    export import point = helpers.point;
}
```

The "turf" monolithic module declaration stays the same:

```
declare module "turf" {
    export = turf;
}
```

And the "@turf/helpers" module declaration looks like this:

```
declare module "@turf/helpers" {
    import helpers = turf.helpers;
    export = helpers;
}
```

So now both usecases are supported:

```
import * as turf from "turf";

import { feature, distanceToDegrees } from "@turf/helpers";

let geometry = {
  "type": "Point",
  "coordinates": [
    67.5,
    32.84267363195431,
  ],
};

turf.feature(geometry); // OK 
feature(geometry); // OK
turf.distanceToDegrees(10) // NOT OK
distanceToDegrees(10); // OK
```